# Odoo Accounting Report returning IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

I'm developing a custom accounting report on Odoo Enterprise. It's first time I try to do this kind of report, so I have a lot of doubts that I haven't solved on internet.

Based on native reports I came to this so far:

```
class BudgetaryPositionCompanyReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = "budgetary.position.report"
    _inherit = "account.report"

    filter_date = {'date_from': '', 'date_to': '', 'filter': 'this_month'}
    filter_unfold_all = False

    def _get_columns_name(self, options):
        return [{'name': _('Budget Item')}, {'name': _('Column1')}, {'name': _('Column2')}, {'name': _('%')}]

    @api.model
    def _get_lines(self, options, line_id=None):
        context = dict(self._context or {})
        date_from = context.get('date_from')
        date_to = context.get('date_to')
        lines = []

        sql_parents = """
        SELECT abp.name "name", sum(cbl.planned_amount) planned_amount, sum(cbl.r_practical_amount) r_practical_amount, sum(cbl.r_percentage) r_percentage
        FROM crossovered_budget_lines cbl
        JOIN account_budget_post abp ON (cbl.general_budget_id = abp.id)
        GROUP BY abp.id;
        """
        self.env.cr.execute(sql_parents)
        results_parents = self.env.cr.dictfetchall()

        for parent in results_parents:
            lines.append({
                    'id': parent.get('id'),
                    'name': parent.get('name'),
                    'level': 1,
                    'unfoldable': True,
                    'unfolded': True,
                    'colspan': 4,
                    'columns': [
                        {'name': parent.get('name') and parent.get('name')},
                        {'name': parent.get('planned_amount') and self.format_value(parent.get('planned_amount'))},
                        {'name': parent.get('r_practical_amount') and self.format_value(parent.get('r_practical_amount'))},
                        {'name': parent.get('r_percentage') and self.format_value(parent.get('r_percentage'))}
                    ],
                })
        print(lines)
        return lines

    def _get_report_name(self):
        return _('Budgetary Positions (per company)')

    def _get_templates(self):
        templates = super(BudgetaryPositionCompanyReport, self)._get_templates()
        return templates
```

Problem is when I try to access to this report, I'm getting the following:

```
Error to render compiling AST
IndexError: list index out of range
Template: account_reports.line_template
Path: /templates/t/t/tr/t[2]/td
Node: <td t-att-class="'o_account_report_line ' + (column.get('class', lines.get('columns_header')[-1][column_index+line.get('colspan', 1)].get('class', '')) + (line.get('unfoldable') and ' o_foldable_total' or '')) + ('' if hierarchies_enabled else ' o_account_report_line_indent')" t-att-style="column.get('style', lines.get('columns_header')[-1][column_index+line.get('colspan', 1)].get('style', ''))">
                    <span class="o_account_report_column_value" t-att-title="column.get('title')">
                        <t t-esc="column.get('name')"/>
                    </span>
                </td>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Odoo is telling there is no data in list at index number 2....... Debug where you used list indexing because some of them is not getting value

Comment: At the moment, the query is returning 1 record. The list is returning one too, I made print and I got: [{'id': 1, 'name': 'TEST', 'level': 1, 'unfoldable': True, 'unfolded': True, 'colspan': 4, 'columns': [{'name': 'TEST'}, {'name': 'CLP 1.900.500'}, {'name': 0.0}, {'name': 0.0}]}]

Comment: The ``column_index+line.get('colspan', 1)`` element does  not exist in the `lines.get('columns_header')[-1]` list.

Comment: deleting the colspan key in the append line it fixed it. I didn't even needed that one.